# Dataset for musical Instruments recognition

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, audio

I am looking for a "rich" Dataset to Teach my model to separate Music instruments.. any Suggestions? I found the URMP Dataset but it doesn't have many files. I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 4):

The [NSynth dataset](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/nsynth) contains labelled audio samples from various instruments over a range of pitches.  The data is prepared for use with TensorFlow and also available in JSON/WAV (metadata/audio) format. From the dataset description:

> NSynth is an audio dataset containing 305,979 musical notes, each with
>   a unique pitch, timbre, and envelope. For 1,006 instruments from
>   commercial sample libraries, we generated four second, monophonic
>   16kHz audio snippets, referred to as notes, by ranging over every
>   pitch of a standard MIDI pian o (21-108) as well as five different
>   velocities (25, 50, 75, 100, 127). The note was held for the first
>   three seconds and allowed to decay for the final second.

The data is released under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International (CC BY 4.0) license.